# Split a string in bash based on delimiter

Tags: bash, split

I have a file log_file which has contents such as

```
CCO O-MR1 Sync:No:3:No:346:Yes
CCO P Sync:No:1:No:106:Yes
CCO P Checkout:Yes:1:No:10:No
CCO O-MR1 Checkout(2.2):Yes:1:No:10:No
```

I am trying to obtain the 4 fields based on ":" delimiter
The script that I have is

```
#!/bin/bash
log_file=$1

for i in `cat $log_file` ; do
        echo $i
        field_a=`echo $i | awk -F '[:]' '{print $1}'`
        echo $field_a
        field_b=`echo $i | awk -F '[:]' '{print $2}'`
        echo $lfield_b
        ...
done
```

but the value that this code gives for field_a is wrong, it splits the line based on " " delimiter.
echo $i also prints wrong value.

What else can I use to correct this?

Comment: See [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). And as an aside, see also [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) -- `echo $foo` should be `echo "$foo"`. http://shellcheck.net/ is also a useful and relevant resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is covered *in detail* in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). To summarize, use a `while read` loop with `IFS` set to contain (only) the characters that should be used to split fields.

```
while IFS=: read -r field_a field_b other_fields; do
  echo "field_a is $field_a"
  echo "field_b is $field_b"
  echo "Remaining fields are $other_fields"
done <"$log_file"
```